# How to get the discriminator from the id of an entitie?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to now wether my id is an invoice or an individualinvoice

individualinvoice.cs

```
    public class IndividualInvoice : Invoice {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

invoice.cs

```
    public class Invoice {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string VATNumber { get; set; }

        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        [Required]
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    }
```

gingsengdbcontext.cs

```
    public class GingsengDbContext : IdentityDbContext<GingsengUser> {
        public DbSet<Gingseng> Gingsengs { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

        public DbSet<IndividualInvoice> IndividualInvoices { get; set; }
        public GingsengDbContext(DbContextOptions<GingsengDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

And here is my controller where i would like to know from the id if the id corresponds to an individialinvoice or just an invoice? is there any cleaner way than to use singleordefault?

```
public class InvoicesController : Controller {
        private readonly GingsengDbContext context;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public InvoicesController(GingsengDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetInvoice(string id) {
            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only clean way which works with all EF Core supported inheritance models (currently TPH and TPT) is to use C# `is` operator. However the classes must not inherit other non abstract class from the same hierarchy like in your example, because `IndividualInvoice` *is a* `Invoice`, hence will be included in `DbSet<Invoice>` and any query (`OfType` etc.) which checking for `Invoice`.

So you can check just for final classes, e.g.

```cs
bool isIndividualInvoice = await context.Invoices
    .AnyAsync(e => e.Id == id && e is IndividualInvoice);
```

which btw is the same as

```cs
bool isIndividualInvoice = await context.IndividualInvoices
    .AnyAsync(e => e.Id == id);
```

and similar (using `Set<IndividualInvoice>()` or `Set<Invoice>().OfType<IndividualInvoice>`).

Another not so clean option which works only for TPH is to retrieve the discriminator property value directly. You have to know its name and type (the defaults are "Discriminator" and `string`) and use the special `EF.Property` method similar to this:

```cs
var type = await context.Invoices
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .Select(e => EF.Property<string>(e, "Discriminator")) // <--
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
// here type will be ether null, "Invoice" or "IndividualInvoice"
```